# Database Multiple Inner Join

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, join

I have question regarding the performance factor for the following question.

Consider a table : Users,

```
 -----userId------- userName-----
        1              ABC
        2              XYZ
```

Another table : Transaction,

```
------createdBy----ReceivedBy----TransactionId
          1            2              50
          2            1              51
```

My required result is,

```
--------createdBy----ReceivedBy----TransactionId----userName_Creator-----userName_Receiver
            1            2               50            ABC                     XYZ
            2            1               51            XYZ                     ABC
```

I came out with two solutions,

1. Using a varied inner join,

> SELECT * FROM
>       Transaction T
>       INNER JOIN
>       (
>         SELECT createdBy,userName FROM Transaction
>         Inner Join
>         Users
>
> ```
> )
> ON createdBy = userId
> INNER JOIN
> (
>   SELECT ReceivedBy,userName FROM Transaction
>   Inner Join
>   Users
> )   
> ON ReceivedBy= userId
> WHERE TransactionId = 51
> ```

2.To maintain an hashmap for all the distinct userId and username and package the output by a look up in the data layer.

Which of these solution is optimal ? Also better technique is welcome.

--Siva

Answer (score 1):

Your query is a good start, but it is unnecessarily complex. Try the following:

```
SELECT createdBy, ReceivedBy, TransactionId, userName
FROM Transaction
INNER JOIN Users ON createdBy = userId
```

Update: Doing it in the query is the better way (in my opinion), since it makes sense to get your data from the database the way you want to have it if possible. If you do (unnecessary) extra operations on your query result, your code will probably be harder to understand. To put it in a query is probably faster too, since your DBMS is optimized for this kind of operation.

Answer (score 0):

why not simply doing something like:

```
select t.createdBy, t.ReceivedBy, t.TransactionId, u.userName
from Transactions u, Users u
where t.createdBy = u.userId
```

Comment: Why are you not using an actual (inner) join?

Comment: that is an inner join, it's just using a different syntax

Comment: @JoeLove Nevermind, I knew the result was the same, thought the performance was different, but apparently it isn't.

Comment: The performance is exactly the same unless you're overriding a planner choice, and in a 2 table scenario that's not possible. See the info in this thread: http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/4921.1052965555@sss.pgh.pa.us

Comment: @JoeLove, guess you missed my update, I also saw the performance was indeed the same. (You should be linking MySQL, not Postgres)

Comment: oops. sorry, but as DBMS's go the issue is basically the same..Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

use this format:

```
SELECT a.batsman_id,a.matchs,a.hundreds,b.country_type, c.player_name
FROM batsman a  
            INNER JOIN countrycode b ON a.country_code=b.country_code
        INNER JOIN players c ON a.player_id=c.player_id
        ORDER BY a.batsman_id;
```